# Dbpedia-spotlight missing resource

Tags: java, spotlight-dbpedia

I build QAS (Question Answering System ) and I use DBpedia as knowledge base so i need find resource in my question like (Algeria , Florida , barack obama ..) , i have problem when i use "dbpedia-spotlight Tool" i can't get all resource i need , Example:

`"birthday of Abbas el-Akkad "` resource is "[Abbas el-Akkad](http://dbpedia.org/page/Abbas_el-Akkad)" but i can't get it with "dbpedia-spotlight" you can try out [here](http://dbpedia-spotlight.github.io/demo/)

Another example :

"`What is the largest city in Australia?`" Correct resource is [Australia](http://dbpedia.org/page/Australia) but i get [Australia_II](http://dbpedia.org/page/Australia_II) .

Please any advice to me for  get correct resources that is on DBpedia resource.
I use default parameters in(dbpedia-spotlight), Java language .

Question get correct resource and correct Answers :

- give me 23rd president of the united states?
- what is capital of Iran
- give me birthdate of obama
- What is the largest city in Chaina?
- what is tall Lionel Messi?
- How tall is Claudia Schiffer?
- Short Description of obama
- how many people in Algeria
- Why is the sky blue?
- how many students in university of manitoba
- Where was George Washington born?
- When was George Washington born?

Answer (score 1):

Spotlight is a context oriented tool. Sometimes it's makes mistakes if you try to annotate small texts.

I tried your question What is the largest city in Australia? and I got success.

Actually, we have been working with two approaches: Lucene - http://spotlight.dbpedia.org/rest/ and Statistical - http://spotlight.sztaki.hu:2222/rest.  For your case,  I recommend you to use Lucene approach.

E.g: 
Why is the sky blue?  - http://spotlight.dbpedia.org/rest/annotate?text=%20Why%20is%20the%20sky%20blue?&confidence=0.3